# Autocreate directories when building

Tags: c, git, mercurial, makefile

I have a project written in `C` and I am using `mercurial` (I can use `git` too) for version control and `GNU` `make` for building. The project includes several empty directories used for build-time generated files, such as dependency makefiles and object files.

When I check out the project, however, empty directories are not created (they are ignored by the version control system) and the build fails.

The only remedy I have in mind is to add a `mkdir -p` directive in every single recipe in the 58 makefiles of the project (it is quite big). Apart from a lot of editing, `mkdir -p` is discouraged in the `GNU` `make` manual for being incompatible with other versions of `make`.

Is there any smarter way to overcome the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Both git and Mercurial track files, not directories, so empty directories will not be stored.

The common trick is to just add an empty file to the directories you need, like:

```
touch output/.empty
```

And then add that to the repository.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had seen this workaround in mercurial and git questions. If there is not another way around this, I think this is a contradiction in the related tools. The version systems do not support empty directories, while build systems need them. There should be a fix for this.

Comment: @Kostas: I think, you had a good reason to go for Mercurial (or Git). Doing so, these tools become **a part** of your build system. Lasse showed you how to add empty directories to the versioning. This solves your problem. If that's too cumbersome for you, maybe you're better off using a different VCS. SVN supports empty folders. But you surely had good reasons for not selecting SVN.

Comment: There is no fix for this, nor will there be in the foreseeable future, if at all. Either you live with this limitation by either tracking empty files, like I showed you, or having your build system create the structure it needs to, or adding a batch file that does that before the build system kicks in, or you use some other VCS.

Answer (score 3):

You can have:

```
output/%: output/.empty

output/.empty:
        $(MKDIR_P) output
        touch output/.empty
```

in the makefile. Than all files in `output` will depend on creating the directory without modifying each rule separately.

The `$(MKDIR_P)` definition (`mkdir -p` for most systems or a special script where that does not work) can be provided by configuration script (e.g. autoconf using `AC_PROG_MKDIR_P`) or conditional setting in the makefile.

Comment: Ok this is quite close to what I had in mind. Basically, I was looking for a means to make ALL targets depending on their directory. Something like:

`%: $(dir %)`
`       $(MKDIR_P) $(dir $@)`

And then make this rule be inherited by all sub-makefiles. Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

As you mention that you could use git as well, maybe that you would be interested by the fact that [bazaar](http://bazaar.canonical.com/) can track directories the same way it does for files. I don't know if it is an option for you, just saying.

Comment: bazaar indeed worked like charm. I might be able to convince the rest of the team to use it, else I will have to use one of the workarounds. Thanks!